# How to create an enum variable using ApolloStack/GraphQL with a special character?

Tags: graphql, apollo

I'm trying to create a GraphQL enum type using ApolloStack. But nothing seems to work. For reference, please see the example code.

```
enum Test {
    ABC
    Dog
    Dog/Cat
}
```

In the example above, Dog/Cat will cause the server to not work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure using '/' is possible when declaring enumeration values.

Try switching the name of 'Dog/Cat' to somthing like 'Animal'

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a special character in an `enum` in GraphQL. But you can handle them with a resolver - except there is a gotcha that you cannot resolve a `Type` in GraphQL, you can only resolve a `field` of a Type.

For example,

```
type Foo {
  test: Test
}
enum Test {
  ABC
  Dog
  DogCat
}
```

and in your resolver for `Foo`,

```
{
  Foo: {
    test({ test }) {
      // handle special characters and return enum supported string
      if (test === "Cat/Dog") return "CatDog";
      return test;
    }
  }
}
```